# Is it possible to add a "Open in Cmder" context menu entry in Windows that sends the folder to the current session and doesn't open a new one?

Tags: windows, terminal, context-menu, cmder

I have Cmder set to autostart with Windows as a drop-down terminal, now I want to add a context-menu entry so whenever I right-click a folder in Windows-Explorer I can open that folder in Cmder.

The Cmder Wiki provides instructions as to how to do so however that opens a new Cmder terminal/session which causes me to have two drop-down terminals overlayed over each other.

Is it possible to send a folder-path to the current, active session instead?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and finally found a way to do it!

You can send any command to an active tab:

```bash
"%CMDER_ROOT%\vendor\conemu-maximus5\ConEmu\ConEmuC64.exe" -guimacro:0 print("echo \"Hello world\"\n"); WindowMode("NOR")
```

Here `-guimacro:0` means to execute the command in the current active tab

`print("echo \"Hello world\"\n")` prints command `echo "Hello world"` to your console and "press" Enter

`WindowMode("NOR")` show cmder if it minimized

For adding Open cmder here use following reg file

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\Cmder]
@="Open Cmder Here"
"Icon"="\"%CMDER_ROOT%\\icons\\cmder.ico\",0"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\Cmder\command]
@="ABS_PATH_TO\\cmder\\vendor\\conemu-maximus5\\ConEmu\\ConEmuC64.exe -guimacro:0 print(\"cd \\\"\"); print(%V); print(\"\\\"\\n\"); WindowMode(\"NOR\")"
```

I split the `cd "%V"` command into 3 parts so that the escape characters are correctly typed into the console

And for some reason `%CMDER_ROOT%\\vendor\\conemu-maximus5\\ConEmu\\ConEmuC64.exe ...`  is not working here